# How to sort by date in Javascript/Angular {{}}

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Say I have this piece of code:

```
<tr  ng-repeat-start="caseHistory in vm.caseHistory">
            <td >{{caseHistory.date | date:"dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a"}}</td>
            <td >{{caseHistory.description}}</td>
            <td >{{caseHistory.performedByUser.firstName}} {{caseHistory.performedByUser.lastName}} ({{caseHistory.performedByUser.externalAssociateId}})</td>
            <td>
                <span ng-show="vm.showCreateCaseComments(caseHistory.eventType,caseHistory.comments)">
                    <a ng-if="caseHistory.expanded" class="removeTextDecoration headerPointer" ng-click="caseHistory.expanded = false"> -Collapse</a>
                    <a ng-if="!caseHistory.expanded" class="removeTextDecoration headerPointer" ng-click="caseHistory.expanded = true"> +Expand</a>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I would like it so that everything that is shown to be sorted by ascending chronological date.

What would I need to add in `{{caseHistory.date | date:"dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a"}}` in order to sort all the results in by the date?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a pipe here:

```
<tr  ng-repeat-start="caseHistory in vm.caseHistory | orderBy:'caseHistory.date'">
```

You could also add the '-' symbol to specify ascending vs descending.

Documentation can be found here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 0):

Use `orderBy` filter and add the reverse option for descending

```
<tr  ng-repeat-start="caseHistory in vm.caseHistory | orderBy: 'date':true">
```

Or add a `-` in front of field name

```
<tr  ng-repeat-start="caseHistory in vm.caseHistory | orderBy: '-date'">
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) Official Tutorial pipe or filter should not be used for sorting purpose.

You can write your custom method to perform this task like :

```
Main.prototype = {

sort: function(item) {
    if (this.predicate == 'date') {
        return new Date(item.date);
    }
    return item[this.predicate];
},

sortBy: function(field) {
    if (this.predicate != field) {
        this.predicate = field;
        this.reverse = false;
    } else {
        this.reverse = !this.reverse;
    }
},

reverse: false};
```

Please refer following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/rvdww/6/) for reference.